# How can I get data for a class object, taking input from user of which object he would like to view?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

First i created a class named 'employed' which looks like this-

```
class employed:
    def __init__(self,name, age, salary, role):
        self.name = name ; self.age = age
        self.salary = salary ; self.role = role

    def givedata(self):
        return(f"name : {self.name}\nage : {self.age}\nsalary : {self.salary}\nrole : {self.role}")
```

Then, i created two class objects for this class-

```
saksham = employed("Saksham", 13, 10000, "developer")
rohan = employed("Rohan", 15, 12000, "team leader")
```

Now i want to take input from the user of which object's data he like to view. How can i do that?

Comment: I just got a way to do that, maybe it's a good way. ```objects = {'saksham' : saksham, 'rohan' : rohan}``` and then I can just call the value. Easy, I don't even require to write a new function for that, my older one will work.

Answer (score 0):

First, we defined a function which returns the user who matches the name
if the function returns none means there is no user that name otherwise it will return user.
Before that, I've added all users into list for convineince

```py
saksham = employed("Saksham", 13, 10000, "developer")
rohan = employed("Rohan", 15, 12000, "team leader")
objects = []
objects.append(saksham)
objects.append(rohan)

def view_object(name):
 for user in objects:
  if user.name == name:
   return user;


name = input("Hey User... Who do you want to view: "

user = view_object(name)
if user is None:
 print("Sorry there is no user with this name")
else:
 print(str(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no switch case in python but you can implement it as follows
define these functions in class

```
def get_name(self):
    return self.name     
def get_salary(self):
    return self.salary
```

then use the following method

```
def numbers_to_months(argument):
    switcher = {
        1: object.get_salary(),
        2: object.get_name(),
    }

    # Get the function from switcher dictionary
    func = switcher.get(argument, lambda: "Invalid month")
    # Execute the function
    print get_salary()
```